# Sub-sequence of characters

Tags: c++

Here have to find the sebsequence of characters in 2 strings..
1st string is **"stackoverflow"** 
2nd string is user input which contains may or may not the string-1 as a sub-sequence of characters.

i.e.,**st**d**ac**hfd**kover**r**flo**o**w**  it contains string1 data as a subsequence characters then output should display **YES**

i.e., "stackoverway" it does not contains string1 data as a subsequence characters then output should display **NO**

Here is my code..

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

bool SubSeq(char str1[], char str2[], int m, int n)
{
if (m == 0) 
    return true;
if (n == 0) 
    return false;

if (str1[m-1] == str2[n-1])
    return SubSeq(str1, str2, m-1, n-1);

return SubSeq(str1, str2, m, n-1);
}

int main()
{
int q;
cin >> q;

for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++)
{
    char str1[] = "stackoverflow";
    int m = strlen(str1);
    char str2[] = "";
    cin >> str2; 
    int n = strlen(str2);
    SubSeq(str1, str2, m, n) ? cout << "YES\n" : cout << "NO\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

In the above code i am getting the output as follows..

```
YES
NO
NO
NO
NO
NO
NO
NO .......(truncated)
```

I don't know why this **NO** occurs so many times..Can anyone tell me where i have done a wrong step..

Thanks in advance

Venkatesh

Comment: First of all, use std::string and not (read only) char arrays.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: What is your input ?

Answer (score 1):

You declare `str2` as empty and then try to store the input into it.Use `std::string`

```
char str1[] = "stackoverflow";
int m = strlen(str1);
char str2[] = ""; //Notice the size of str2
cin >> str2;
```

You can also follow the below approach

Keep on searching for the first character of `to_be_searched` in `search_here`.When found say at `i` position, continue from `i+1` position for the second character of `to_be_searched` and son on.

```
bool check(string to_be_Searched,string search_here)
{
    for(int i=0,j=0;j<to_be_searched.length() && i<search_here.length();i++)
    {
       if(to_be_Searched[j]==search_here[i])
          j++;
    }
    return j==to_be_searched.length();
 }
```